# Hide primary axis in flutter chart

Tags: flutter, charts

I have a primary axis defined as follows:

```
primaryMeasureAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
  tickProviderSpec: new charts.StaticNumericTickProviderSpec(
    <charts.TickSpec<num>>[
      charts.TickSpec<num>(_serverData.minVal),
      charts.TickSpec<num>(_serverData.maxVal),
    ],
  ),
),
```

How can I hide the axis while maintaining the `TickSpec`?

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

Got the solution:

```
renderSpec: new charts.NoneRenderSpec()
```

A full implementation for hiding the domain axis on a LineChart is here

```
charts.LineChart(chartData,
                defaultRenderer: new charts.LineRendererConfig(
                    includeArea: true, stacked: true),
                animate: false,
              domainAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
                  showAxisLine: true,
                  renderSpec: new charts.NoneRenderSpec()),),
```

Answer (score 2):

for line chart this worked for me:

```
// hide x axis
  domainAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
      showAxisLine: false, renderSpec: charts.NoneRenderSpec()),
  // hide y axis
  primaryMeasureAxis:
      charts.NumericAxisSpec(renderSpec: charts.NoneRenderSpec()),
```

more at: https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/axes/hidden_ticks_and_labels_axis.html